# Windows 7 freezes while watching videos with uTorrent opened

Tags: windows-7, video, freeze, utorrent

I having a problem with my new computer. And I think it's related with my graphic card.
I have a Nvidia MSI 770 OC TF, with MSI motherboard.
It works fine, and run games like Assassin's Creed 4 to maximum without problem.

But, **when I watch videos/movies, the computer have random freeze/ultra slow** (which never stop until I reset) issue. Nothing is overheating, and since games runs well, I don't think it can be a hardware problem.

An interesting fact is that mostly (I cannot be sure of it cause I didn't pay attention each time), **it happens while uTorrent is opened**. I didn't have the problem since some days because I cut uTorrent each time I watch a movie.

**So I wonder if it's even possible uTorrent be involved, and how it could be.**

Note: The PC did freeze, two times, while playing, and I'm pretty sure uTorrent was opened at this times. I use Windows 7 64bits Home Premium, with i7 4770k (not OC).

Comment: I use Windows 7 64bits Home Premium, with i7 4770k (not OC)

Answer (score 1):

uTorrent can be the cause, but my first suggestion would be this.

You did not specify which windows version you are using, so if I'd give you instructions for windows 7, they might not be the same as with windows 8. So here comes what you should do without instructions. Feel free to supply your windows version so I can alter the answer and add the instructions if still necesary.

```
Go to your power management options, and change from Balanced to 
High Performance.
```

---

Now that I know you're using Windows 7, here's the easiest way to change the power settings.

```
1. Go to your desktop.
2. Right click an empty section, and choose Personalise.
3. Click on the screensaver icon (bottom right)
4. Click on Change Power settings, (bottom)
5. Click Show Additional plans
6. Tick High performance
7. Click the [x] button to close the window
8. Press ok to exit the screensaver dialog.
9. Close the Personalise dialog.
```

Comment: I did add a comment to my question. I will try what you said

Comment: For the moment it seems to work (I will continue testing for one week at least). Can you explain me why it can have an impact ?

Comment: When you set it to balanced power management, Windows will try to balance between saving power and optimal performance. Tasks such as uTorrent are flagged as background tasks, and thus windows will limit the CPU usage. uTorrent however is a pretty heavy program and eats resources. The tasks you're trying to do in conjunction with uTorrent on that caused these massive slow downs are not tasks that "require" a high CPU usage either, so power management fails to set the CPU usage to maximum. This causes the stutters. High performance always keeps the CPU max speed to 100%, so there's no limiting.

Comment: Problem appears again, even with the power settings to high performances. It did several times in a row on the same video file with uTorrent open (like 4 or 5 times), then I didn't reopen uTorrent and everything ran fine.
Other ideas ?

Comment: uTorrent is a heavy program, so its likely just uTorrent. Maximum performance optimises the CPU usage so that makes it better, but there can be several other reasons. For example uTorrent 3 and higher are far heavier than the latest uTorrent 2 build, which is why I never switched to version 3 when I was still using uTorrent. See if you can find that version somewhere and try that.

Comment: I installed bitTorrent as an alternative and will say you if it solves the problem.

Comment: It likely won't. By the nature of how a bittorrent program works, all programs are heavy. Some are more heavy than others though. You're likely to get a better result by tweaking its advanced settings.

Comment: Indeed it didn't. I will just end up closing torrents while watching video or gaming.